# Clicks on textview not transferred to underlying drawable

Tags: android, layout

I have a Listview with a background state (XML) Drawable for each item.
On top of this drawable I have a TextView.

When the textview is pressed, I want the state drawable to change accordingly.

However that does not happen. What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: From ArrayAdapter getView method I have :

```
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setTypeface(tf);
        name.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        name.setOnClickListener(this);
```

This is a part of the XML for the item layout :

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relative2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"   
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"     
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"     
    android:background="@drawable/blue_bar">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"  
        android:gravity="center_vertical"        
        android:focusable="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:ellipsize="end">
    </TextView>
```

Comment: can you post the code in your activity that's supposed to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you are not getting touch events from TextView?

Add this tag on TextView:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: I do get click events from TextView, but the click is not transferred to the underlying state drawable (blue_bar).

Comment: Ok I think that I have to handle this programatically and add both an onTouchListener to my background view and my textview, and let it choose my state drawable.